# Using MPMoviePlayerController will make the assistive touch disappear

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have written an App which use the MPMoviePlayerController class to play some .mov files in a sub-view. On iOS5 all the things work as design.

However, I found some strange things happened when it is run on iOS6 - the assistive touch is being disappear when the video start to play and will re-appear when the video is paused or stopped either automatically or by user.

Moreover, when I try to release the player and return to the parent view using following code:

```
[player stop];
[player.view removeFromSuperView];

[player release];
```

The assistive touch will be disappear throughout my App, until I press the hard home key once and re-enter my App.

After some testing, the wrap around method I try to keep the assistive touch still visible after movie playing, is to matching the call `[player stop]` with `[player play]`, I.e. I have to check if the player is already stopped or paused, I have to skip the `[player stop]` call when I release the player.

Is there anyone with a similar issue or just me?